# Pyspark - after groupByKey and count distinct value according to the key?

Tags: pyspark

I would like to find how many distinct values according to the key, for example, suppose I have

```
x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1),  ("b", 2), ("a", 2)])
```

And I have done using groupByKey

```
sorted(x.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect())
x.groupByKey().mapValues(len).collect()
```

the output will by like,

```
[('a', [1, 1, 2]), ('b', [1, 2])]
[('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

However,  I want to find distinct values in the list, the output should be like,

```
[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [1, 2])]
[('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

I am very new to spark and try to apply the distinct() function somewhere, but all failed :-( 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use set instead of list -

```
sorted(x.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], set(x[1]))).collect())
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try number of approaches for same. I solved it using below approach:-

```
from operator import add
x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1),  ("b", 2), ("a", 2)])
x = x.map(lambda n:((n[0],n[1]), 1))
x.groupByKey().map(lambda n:(n[0][0],1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()
```

**OutPut:-**

```
[('b', 2), ('a', 2)]
```

Hope This will help you.